# Can I rename the description field in a custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types

We are creating a custom post type with field names that are easy to identify and remember. Our partner explained that the description field cannot be renamed. Is this true?

Comment: The `description` parameter when [registering a post type](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Arguments)? As far as I know it isn't used anywhere unless the theme specifies it but it can be updated to display a different description after registration but the parameter key itself cannot be renamed. Could you edit your question and post an example or use-case, please?

Comment: Second to Howdy's comment.  As long as you have a good backup, you should be perfectly fine to change the description text.

Answer (score 0):

although I'm very much unfamiliar the "description" field, but you can change all the properties of a custom post type, always have a backup of it before making any change, answer for changing name is already available on this forum, go through the following link.

[How do I safely change the name of a custom post type?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/97026/how-do-i-safely-change-the-name-of-a-custom-post-type)